# how to parse json from url in android

Tags: java, android, json

I stuck in this problem how to parse json in from a url in android studio
below is my json structure tried all other methods did'nt work for me

url : http://api.ipstack.com/109.94.137.130?access_key=e9e5de2c993dc6652ed45c3f9dc53daf

```
{
   "ip":"109.94.137.130",
   "type":"ipv4",
   "continent_code":"EU",
   "continent_name":"Europe",
   "country_code":"GB",
   "country_name":"United Kingdom",
   "region_code":"ENG",
   "region_name":"England",
   "city":"Bedford",
   "zip":"MK42",
   "latitude":52.1073,
   "longitude":-0.4649,
   "location":{
      "geoname_id":2656046,
      "capital":"London",
      "languages":[
         {
            "code":"en",
            "name":"English",
            "native":"English"
         }
      ],
      "country_flag":"http:\/\/assets.ipstack.com\/flags\/gb.svg",
      "country_flag_emoji":"\ud83c\uddec\ud83c\udde7",
      "country_flag_emoji_unicode":"U+1F1EC U+1F1E7",
      "calling_code":"44",
      "is_eu":true
   }
}
```

please help regarding this issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: explain clearly, what you want ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: What have you tried so far . show your effort

Comment: `tried all other methods` if you really tried all the methods, then we can't help you.

Comment: also it is a bad idea to share your private access key with entire world.

Comment: please show the method you already tried

Answer (score 1):

Getting the data from API using retrofit or volley. [Sample Retrofit Implementation](https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23)

Use [GSON](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-getting-started-with-java-json-serialization-deserialization) library for parsing gson. As, it's easy to implement it.

Parsing code snippet is:

```
ModelClass sInfo_parse = new Gson().fromJson(getURLJson, ModelClass.class);
```

Answer (score -2):

Add volley in your gradle file from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley). Now add below line in your java file.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ChangePasswordActivity.this);
```

Now call make StringRequest constructor in onCreate method like below method.

```
        String Url = your url

                    Log.d(TAG, Url);

                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    Log.d("response", response);

// here you can find your all json value.
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    error.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                    );

                    queue.add(stringRequest);
                }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, please add some explanation as to why it does. This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.

Comment: can u help me to retrieve at least one value from the json structure

Comment: which value do you want to retrieve according to you json file